# Maven - Skip reporting on specific modules

Tags: maven-3

I am looking for a solution to skip some maven reporting on modules that are not critical to the final product. Such as modules that are unit tests only, or a third party plug-in like Log4J.

I have a parent POM, with in modules defined.

```
<project>
  <modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
    <module>module4</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

There are also dependencies and profiles. Please keep in mind, this project fully builds. Im looking to reduce the time for a mvn package site to complete (currently over 30min)

Stepping into Module1 there is the parent info, the artifact id, and packaging (pom). Then more sub-modules are defined

```
<modules> 
    <module>package1</module>
    <module>package2</module>
    <module>package1.tests</module>
</modules>
```

It is this package1.test that I want to skip the reporting on.

Most of what I can find about this revolves around plugins such as this from the maven website:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <skip>true</skip>
      <skipDeploy>true</skipDeploy>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

but I am not seeing how to apply this to the modules. and I did try adding the `<config>` and `<skip>` to the modules lines.

I would greatly appreciate some suggestions. I am new to world of maven so explanations are very welcome.

Using maven 3.0.4 currently.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not seeing how to apply this to the modules. and I did try
>   adding the  and  to the modules lines.

The maven site plugin configuration to skip the site generation and deployment applies to project poms and not to modules.  You can add the above snippet to each project pom for which you do not want site information to be generated.

Comment: So I need to put that snippet inside the POM of project1.tests? Thanks, I'll give that a go.